# Attain information about installed Ubuntu packages

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

What is the best tool that, for any given package, attain the following, if possible, information:

- What is the package used for?
- When was it installed?
- Was this package installed manually or was it required by another package?
- Are there any packages currently installed that depends on this package, i.e. will something break if it is removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a great question. You would think that there would be one nice, handy-dandy tool to tell you such things, but I don't know it. I'll go one by one, and give my best suggestions.

> 1. What is the package used for?
> 2. When was it installed?
> 3. Was this package installed manually
>      or was it required by another
>      package?
> 4. Are there any packages currently
>      installed that depends on this
>      package, i.e. will something break
>      if it is removed?

1. On the command line, `aptitude show
   package` or `apt-cache show package`
   will provide a description of the
   package, as well as a lot of other
   information. Synaptic allows you to
   search for an item in various ways,
   and it provides a description of the
   package. (The descriptions you get
   from all these methods are
   identical. They all get their
   information from the same place in a
   .deb, I believe.)
2. Such a simple thing, but other than
   digging through logs, I can't think
   of how to do this. Synaptic doesn't
   seem to keep this information as
   meta-data. (This would make a great
   wish-list bug.) Here's one way to do
   it:

   ```
   zgrep package /var/log/dpkg*
   ```

   That's a bit cludgy, and it will
   produce a lot of output, but it
   should also get you the date you
   want. (You need `zgrep` since older
   logs will be gunzipped archives.) By the way, you need to be root even to search `dpkg`'s logs.
3. If you run `aptitude show package`
   on an installed package, check the
   field "Automatically installed." If it says yes, it was brought
   in as a dependency of some other
   package. (For the record, there are
   things you can do to manually change
   this setting. That is, you can
   mark a package to look manually
   installed, even though it was
   actually installed as a dependency.
   But for the most part, the results
   here should be valid.) You can also
   filter Synaptic searches to look for
   things installed as dependencies.
4. A brute-force way to check this:

   ```
   aptitude -s remove package
   ```

   The `-s` flag simulates commands.
   You can run such a command as a
   regular user, and there's no danger
   of actually harming your system. It
   allows you to see easily what the
   proposed action would do. One thing
   to keep in mind is that this sort of
   check will show you *gross*
   breakage, but it won't show broader
   mistakes. What I mean is you might
   be able to remove package Foo
   without truly breaking your system,
   but it may severely limit the
   usefulness of package Bar. In
   general, packages are chained
   together through recommendations to
   prevent just this, but it's worth
   keeping in mind. You can also search for dependencies and reverse dependencies using `apt-cache`, but I find the simulated run is the most vivid way of seeing what will happen.

One other general search tip for Aptitude. On the command line, you can use these searches to quickly see what you have installed by choice versus what was installed automatically as a dependency of something else:

```
aptitude search '~i !~M' # Find things not installed as something else's dependency
aptitude search '~i ~M'  # Find things installed as something else's dependency
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you... while it looks like its possible to get all the information I want, I would prefer to have a gui, like Synaptic, but built for survey rather than install/remove/upgrade. The very core of the question is a way to answer "Do I really need this package?", as I aim to clean up the OS on this box a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The [Debian User Manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/user-manuals#apt-howto) has a section on [APT](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkgtools.en.html#s-apt-get) which describes the commands to search / query and interrogate the currently installed and repository packages.

For example the command below will show detailed information regarding a specific installed application.

```
apt-cache showpkg package
```